Calderón–Zygmund inequality for Neumann problems
My question is simple:
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain. Does the following inequality $$\|D^2w\|_{L^q(\Omega)}\leq C\|\Delta w\|_{L^q(\Omega)},$$ hold for any function $w\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap C^1(\overline \Omega)$, such that $\frac{\partial w}{\partial \eta}=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $\eta$ denotes the outward normal vector, $C$ is a positive constant, $D^2w$ denotes the Hessian of $w$, and $\Delta w$ is the Laplacian of $w$?
I am familiar with the theory in the local case and under Dirichlet boundary condition.

Yes, it's true. Check Theorem 2.3.3.6 of the book

P. Grisvard. Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains, volume 24 of Monographs and Studies in Mathematics. Pitman (Advanced Publishing Program), Boston, MA, 1985.


Thank you for the reference.
P.S. Felice Iandoli sends his regards

Piacere. E salutami lo !
